# How to turn off animations in WPF Toolkit charts

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

Is there a way to turn off the animations in Xaml directly? The animations are really sluggish as my chart has many points.

Answer (score 1):

i have downloaded the latest source code at http://wpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

my idea is, to remove the animation by changing the style for the different chart series (chart points, DataPointStyle)

example for `charting:PieDataPoint`

try to remove the animation for the shown data and take your own style with a given key (x:key="myStyle" -> `DataPointStyle="{StaticResource myStyle}"`)

and remove `Opacity="0"` at `<Grid x:Name="Root" Opacity="0">`

remove this visual state group from your style

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="RevealStates">
    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5" />
    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
    <VisualState x:Name="Shown">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Hidden">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0" />
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

**EDIT**

This is the changed style.

```
<!--  charting:PieDataPoint  -->
<Style TargetType="charting:PieDataPoint">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="RatioStringFormat" Value="{}{0:p2}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:PieDataPoint">
                <Grid x:Name="Root" Opacity="0">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverHighlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.6" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionHighlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.6" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Path x:Name="Slice" Data="{TemplateBinding Geometry}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeMiterLimit="1">
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}" />
                                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding FormattedRatio}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    </Path>
                    <Path x:Name="SelectionHighlight" Data="{TemplateBinding GeometrySelection}" Fill="Red" StrokeMiterLimit="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" />
                    <Path x:Name="MouseOverHighlight" Data="{TemplateBinding GeometryHighlight}" Fill="White" StrokeMiterLimit="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

After my first attempt to remove the animation, I wanted to give up, because it has not worked.

But then I looked upon me with the reflector to the source code and have found a way that it still works.

Setting the DataPointStyle unfortunately is not enough, I think it's a bug.

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Margin="8">

  <chartingToolkit:Chart.Series>
    <chartingToolkit:BarSeries x:Name="barSeries"
                                Title="Experience"
                                DataPointStyle="{StaticResource myBarStyle}">
    </chartingToolkit:BarSeries>
  </chartingToolkit:Chart.Series>

</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

In the constructor of the control where the chart is included simply execute the following.

```
this.barSeries.RefreshStyles();
```

hope this helps