# Simulate a long mouseOver wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseover

I have a datagrid which contains hyperlinks in a DatagridTemplateColumn like the following :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="170" SortMemberPath="Joueur.EtatCivil.Joueur_nom"  CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="True" Header="">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate />
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource DatagridCellHyperlinkStyle}" >
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Width="Auto"  VerticalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <TextBlock Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Width="Auto" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">
                        <Hyperlink IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}">
                         <InlineUIContainer TextDecorations="{Binding Path=TextDecorations, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBlock}}" Foreground="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBlock}}">
                          <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding DataContext.Joueur.EtatCivil.NomComplet, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"/>

                         </InlineUIContainer>
                            <Hyperlink.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Hyperlink" BasedOn="{StaticResource HyperlinkStyle}">
                                    <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="ClickEvent" />
                                    <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.MouseEnter" Handler="MouseOverEvent" />
                                    <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.MouseLeave" Handler="ClicJoueurMouseLeaveEvent" />                                        
                                </Style>
                            </Hyperlink.Style>
                        </Hyperlink>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This works fine and as expected but I have trouble when I just move my cursor hover many lines in a small time (<0.5s maybe).

My MouseEnterEvent calls a method named "Show();" and my MouseLeaveEvent a method named "Hide();"

This show/hide a small popup to display to the user more data. The problem is that my show(); method update a Wpf toolkit chart which seems to have trouble to be updated with this frequency (10 times in 0.5s). The binding seems to "crash" and never works again.
this helped me : [Binding update adds news series to WPF Toolkit chart (instead of replacing/updating series)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039141/binding-update-adds-news-series-to-wpf-toolkit-chart-instead-of-replacing-updat/3234889#3234889) )

I update my chart like this :

```
this.colonnes.ItemsSource = null;
                _DataGraph = new ObservableCollection<GraphiqueValeurs>();

                _DataGraph.Add(new GraphiqueValeurs(value, "my string");

                this.colonnes.ItemsSource = _DataGraph;


                this.colonnes.UpdateLayout();
```

With the following xaml :

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="/BPM2015;component/#Open Sans Condensed" BorderBrush="Transparent" Name="columnChart" Title="Column Series Demo" Foreground="{DynamicResource CouleurTexte}" >
            <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries Name="colonnes" Foreground="{DynamicResource CouleurTexte}"  DependentValueBinding="{Binding Valeur}"
        IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
        DataPointStyle="{StaticResource ColorByPreferenceColumn}" 
                                          >
    <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
        <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Minimum="0" Maximum="20" Title="" Foreground="Transparent" ShowGridLines="True">
            <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis.MajorTickMarkStyle>
                <Style TargetType="Line">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </Style>
            </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis.MajorTickMarkStyle>
        </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis>
    </chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.DependentRangeAxis>

</chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries>

<chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
    <Style TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
    </Style>
</chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
<chartingToolkit:Chart.TitleStyle>
    <Style TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
    </Style>
</chartingToolkit:Chart.TitleStyle>
```

So my question is : How I can avoid all these quick mouseEnter ? I'd like to avoid my mouseEnter function to call the "Show()" method if the cursor doesn't stay at least 0.4s on the hyperlink.

How could I do that ?

This

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `DispatcherTimer` to add a delay to calling your function and combine that with a `bool` flag that is set to `true` in the `MouseEnter` handler and set to `false` in the `MouseLeave` handler. Try this:

```
private DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
private isMouseOver = false;
```

...

```
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400);
timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
```

...

```
private void MouseEnterHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    isMouseOver = true;
    timer.Start();
}

private void MouseLeaveHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    isMouseOver = false;
    timer.Stop();
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isMouseOver) Show();
    timer.Stop();
}
```